# Need to convert result of .innerHTML to number on javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a html that contains tables like the following example

```html
<td class="topiccell">
    <span class="topicnormal">
        <a class="value" href="/topic/?lang=en&action=viewtopic&topic=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wandora.org%2Fsparql%2Fresultset%2Fliteral%2F40">
                 40
        </a>
    </span>
</td>
<td class="topiccell">
   <span class="topicnormal">
       <a class="value" href="/topic/?lang=en&action=viewtopic&topic=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wandora.org%2Fsparql%2Fresultset%2Fliteral%2F40">
                 3
        </a>
   </span>
</td>
```

and I need to parse 40, 3 and another 75 numbers using `.innerHTML`. Then I would like to make a sum of all 75 numbers. I used the following

```
var valuelements = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
var features = new Array(valuelements.length);
for (var i=0; i<=features.length; i++){ 
  var val = valuelements[i].innerHTML;
  var counter = counter + val;
}
document.write(counter);
```

and the result was like 40 3 etc.... tried `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `.value` but the result always was `NaN.` Any suggestions?

Comment: you could try: var val = Number(valuelements[i].innerHTML);
or var val = parseInt(valuelements[i].innerHTML);
and declare your var counter outside the loop

Comment: 1*s is your friend.  If s is a string representation of a number, 1*s is a number. Also javascript does not have block scope variables, so declare all vars outside the for block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to initialize `counter` with a starting number, otherwise you're performing math on `undefined`.

```
var counter = 0;
```

And then in the loop, use `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, or a direct number conversion  on the `.innerHTML` value.

```
var counter = 0;

for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++){ 
  counter += parseFloat(valuelements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

---

In a modern browser, you could do this:

```
var count = [].reduce.call(valueelements, function(c, v) {
    return c + parseFloat(v.innerHTML);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!Ok, tried all your answers and now is telling me that "Error:valuelements[i] is undefined" . I tried to make new Array(valuelements.length) but keeps telling is undefined... How to fix it?

Comment: @user2027553: I didn't notice you had `<=` in your `for` loop. It should just be `<`, as in `i<features.length`. I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, using a more functional approach:

```
var sum = [].map.call(valuelements, function(v) {
  return +v.textContent; }).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
```

Comment: Just a note... Even though you're pre-mapping the elements to numbers, you should still provide a seed for `.reduce` just in case there are no `valuelements` found. With no seed, `.reduce` will throw an error when called on an empty Array. Ex: `[].map(Number).reduce(Number); // TypeError` ... `[].map(Number).reduce(Number, 0); // 0`

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be good practice. I assumed OP _has_ elements.