# cannot convert input text to int in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to sort a table in HTML by clicking the table header. The sorting is fine for strings, but when comparing numbers, it evaluates "10" < "2". Obviously, I'm comparing strings, but I can't get a number out of my table cell. Here's a working example of what's going on:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
      function sortBy() {
          var table = document.getElementById("table");
          var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
          var number = rows[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
          document.write(number);  // This should be printing "7".
      }
 </script>

 <?php 
      echo "<table id='table'>
         <thead><tr><th onclick='sortBy()'>CLICK ME</th></thead></tr>
         <tbody><td><input readonly value='7'></td></tbody>";
 ?>
```

In this example, I'm trying to get the integer `7`. I've tried `parseInt(number)`, but that evaluates to `NaN`, so I tried writing what `number` was and it prints a textfield instead of the textfield's content. I've checked this by printing `number.length`, and I get `29`, rather than `1`.

I've tried `number.value` but that's `undefined`.

I've tried replacing `.innerHTML` with `.value`, but that's `undefined` too.

Is there some way I can convert this into a number? Or at least strip away the html tags and such? I realize I can rig up my own compare logic using the string and it's length ( if (A.length > B.length) { A's bigger } else { compare like normal } ), but that's messy and won't help me to understand this problem.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617221/need-to-convert-result-of-innerhtml-to-number-on-javascript

Comment: You should be selecting the `<input>`, **NOT** the `<td>`. That's why you get a `NaN`. You need to append another `getElementsByTagName(..)[0]` to get the input, then you get its `value` attr.

Comment: @RompePC You should post that as an answer, not in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't picking the correct tag; you need to add a selector for the `<input>` that holds the value.

```
function sortBy() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var number = rows[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("value");
    document.write(number);  // This should be printing "7".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) in order to retrieve and parse value correctly:

```
var number = rows[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getAttribute('value')
document.write(parseInt(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside that the table structure need some corrections, by using `innerHTML` function you will output everything that `td` tag contains. 
To correct JavaScript code I would suggest to use query selector as below:

```js
function sortBy() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var number = rows[1].querySelector("td > input").value;
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick='sortBy()'>CLICK ME</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input readonly value='7'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `Number()` function to create a new Number wrapper class with the value from the string. This should continue to work even if the value is actually a number.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
      function sortBy() {
          var table = document.getElementById("table");
          var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
          var number = rows[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
          document.write(Number(number));  // This should be printing "7".
      }
 </script>

 <?php 
      echo "<table id='table'>
         <thead><tr><th onclick='sortBy()'>CLICK ME</th></thead></tr>
         <tbody><td><input readonly value='7'></td></tbody>";
 ?>
```

Read more in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) page.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't for me. I think the issue is not with the conversion then. Maybe you should be using `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` to select the number.